# Why does setting a static value in array of any[] picks the record but not if set dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to put the index in the array but it fails. When I put a static number

```
let Id: any= this.selectedID;
this.Name= this.secs[Id].Name;
```

but on the `this.secs[Id].Name;` it fails. Even it has the value i.e. `114`. But when I put the same `114` statically like this:

```
let Id: any= this.selectedID;
this.Name= this.secs[114].Name;
```

then it works otherwise `undefined`.

`this.secs` is of type any and is filled on `ngOnInit`

Why ? I have been struggling with it for th past many hours but still not working.

Comment: Doesn't work at compile or runtime?

Comment: And what is the actual type and values of `Id` at the time you try to access the array. Don't guess, check. Seems like `Id` might be coming from an input and therefore could be having the wrong type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is declared like this `let Id: any`, which means that it's of any type.

Arrays in TS can only be indexed with `number` or `string` (or a subset of them), but not anything else.

When you use `114` that's accepted by TS, but when using `id` that doesn't work.

You can try to cast `Id` to `number` and that will work.